# How to get changes in a column and the first appearance of an ID

Tags: sql, db2

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V24B2.png)

From the table in the image, i want to select the first time an DEVID appears and everytime the sensortype of the DEVID changes. So all the yellow rows. I found the separate sql queries to get this results, can someone help combining them.

First result DEVID->

```
 select * from
    (select *, row_number() over 
         (partition by devid order by MSGID ASC) as TopOne from RAWDATA
    ) T
where T.TopOne = 1;
```

change SENSORTYPE of DEVID ->

```
SELECT a.*
FROM rawdata AS a
WHERE a.SENSORTYPE <>
      ( SELECT b.SENSORTYPE
        FROM rawdata AS b
        WHERE b.DEVID = a.DEVID
          AND a.MSGID > b.MSGID
        ORDER BY b.MSGID DESC
        LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And also take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to **dense_rank** function

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             dense_rank(sensortype) over (partition by devid order by id) as top_sensortype
      from rawdata r
     ) r
where top_sensortype=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `lag()`:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             lag(sensortype) over (partition by devid order by id) as prev_sensortype
      from rawdata r
     ) r
where prev_sensortype is null or prev_sensortype <> sensortype;
```